# Modifying the htaccess file for an ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I'm having trouble with my `htaccess` file. Basically at the moment I do this:

when the user is on this url:

```
http://123.org/dashboard/releases.html
```

I direct them to this file:

```
pages/dashboard/press_releasesv4.dashboard.php
```

However, on the same page I've got this `jQuery` code I use to make an `Ajax` request:

```
$('#search-pr-btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //Get the from date
    $sday = $('[name=sday]').val();
    $smonth = $('[name=smonth]').val();
    $syear = $('[name=syear]').val();
    $stime = $('[name=stime]').val();
    $from = $sday+"-"+$smonth+"-"+$syear+" "+$stime+":00";

    //Get the to date
    $eday = $('[name=eday]').val();
    $emonth = $('[name=emonth]').val();
    $eyear = $('[name=eyear]').val();
    $etime = $('[name=etime]').val();
    $to = $eday+"-"+$emonth+"-"+$eyear+" "+$etime+":00";

    //Make AJAX request 
    $('#test').load('pages/ajax/get_press_releases.php', {'from': $from, 'to': $to},function(response, status, xhr){});
});
```

I then added the following to my `htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^dashboard/releases.html                            pages/ajax/get_press_releases.php
```

But now I am getting a `404` when I go to the releases.html page and press the search button. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Your title... Server can't to separate ajax request from, say, form sending...

Comment: You mean the title of the question?

Comment: no matters. to help you we need to know more. Why you  use relative `pages/aj...` but not absolute `/pages/ajax/...` url?

Comment: Please paste here a line from apache error_log and access_log to show more details